# Compare boost::any contents

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I am using a container to hold a list of pointers to anything:

```
struct Example {
    std::vector<boost::any> elements;
}
```

To insert elements in this container, I had written a couple of helper functions (members of the `struct Example`):

```
void add_any(boost::any& a) {
    elements.push_back(a);
}

template<typename T>
void add_to_list(T& a) {
    boost::any bany = &a;
    add_any(bany);
}
```

Now, I would like to insert elements only when they are not present in this container. To do this, I thought that I would only need to call `search` over `elements` with an appropriate comparator function. However, I do not know how to compare the `boost::any` instances.

**My question:**
Knowing that my `boost::any` instances always contain a pointer to something; is it possible to compare two `boost::any` values?

---

**update**

I thank you for your answers. I have also managed to do this in a *probably* unsafe way: using `boost::unsafe_any_cast` to obtain a `void**` and comparing the underlying pointer.

For the moment, this is working fine. I would, however, appreciate your comments: maybe this is a big mistake!

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool any_compare(const boost::any& a1, const boost::any& a2) {
    cout << "compare " << *boost::unsafe_any_cast<void*>(&a1)
         << " with:  " << *boost::unsafe_any_cast<void*>(&a2);
    return (*boost::unsafe_any_cast<void*>(&a1)) ==
        (*boost::unsafe_any_cast<void*>(&a2));
}

struct A {};

class Example {
public:
    Example() : elements(0),
                m_1(3.14),
                m_2(42),
                m_3("hello"),
                m_4() {};
    virtual ~Example() {};

    void test_insert() {
        add_to_list(m_1);
        add_to_list(m_2);
        add_to_list(m_3);
        add_to_list(m_4);
        add_to_list(m_1); // should not insert
        add_to_list(m_2); // should not insert
        add_to_list(m_3); // should not insert 
        add_to_list(m_4); // should not insert
    };

    template <typename T>
    void add_to_list(T& a) { 
        boost::any bany = &a;
        add_any(bany);
    }

private:
    vector<boost::any> elements;
    double m_1;
    int    m_2;
    string m_3;
    A      m_4;


    void add_any(const boost::any& a) {
        cout << "Trying to insert " << (*boost::unsafe_any_cast<void*>(&a)) << endl;
        vector<boost::any>::const_iterator it;
        for (it =  elements.begin();
             it != elements.end();
             ++it) {
            if ( any_compare(a,*it) ) {
                cout << " : not inserting, already in list" << endl;
                return;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Inserting " << (*boost::unsafe_any_cast<void*>(&a)) << endl;
        elements.push_back(a);
    };


};



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Example ex;
    ex.test_insert();
    unsigned char c;
    ex.add_to_list(c);
    ex.add_to_list(c); // should not insert

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Your `add_any` and `add_to_list` functions should take a const-reference as parameter. Also, you might consider using a `set` instead of a `vector` if you want uniqueness. You'd still need a comparison function of course.

Comment: Good question. It is probably not possible. However, if you're willing to implement *your own* any, there is a way to do it (with *run time fail* if the underlying types are both the same, but do not support comparison semantics)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to store the address of the parameter to the `add_to_list` helper? Note that `boost::any` will copy the object, but in this case the object is a pointer.

Comment: @David: Yes, this is exactly what I intended. I do not wish to copy the object (which may be big or un-copyable).

Comment: any reason for not using a `void*` then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only easy way to do this I can think of involves hardcoding support for the types that you're storing in the `any` instances, undermining much of the usefulness of `any`...

```
bool equal(const boost::any& lhs, const boost::any& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.type() != rhs.type())
        return false;

    if (lhs.type() == typeid(std::string))
        return any_cast<std::string>(lhs) == any_cast<std::string>(rhs);

    if (lhs.type() == typeid(int))
        return any_cast<int>(lhs) == any_cast<int>(rhs);

    // ...

    throw std::runtime_error("comparison of any unimplemented for type");
}
```

With C++11's [`type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) you could use a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` keyed on `std::type_index(some_boost_any_object.type())` - similar to what Alexandre suggests in his comment below.

Comment: a `map<std::type_info*, bool(const any&, const any&)>` should be more scalable.

Comment: @Alexandre: won't work reliably though... my recollection is that you can have multiple type_info objects for the same type (per translation unit, not guaranteed to be removed by the linker), so you need to be comparing the `type_info`s with the provided `operator==`... even mapping from `type_info->name()` is non-portable because implementations are allowed to provide any value including an empty string or a constant value across types.  `type_info`'s just so special, you've got to love it!

Comment: @Alexandre: `std::type_info::before`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly provide it, but you can actually use `any` as the underlying type... though for pointers it's pointless (ah!)

```
struct any {
  std::type_info const& _info;
  void* _address;
};
```

And a templated constructor:

```
template <typename T>
any::any(T* t):
   _info(typeid(*t)),
   _address(dynamic_cast<void*>(t))
{
}
```

This is, basically, `boost::any`.

Now we need to "augment" it with our comparison mechanism.

In order to do so, we'll "capture" the implementation of `std::less`.

```
typedef bool (*Comparer)(void*,void*);

template <typename T>
bool compare(void* lhs, void* rhs) const {
  return std::less<T>()(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(lhs), *reinterpret_cast<T*>(rhs));
}

template <typename T>
Comparer make_comparer(T*) { return compare<T>; }
```

And augment the constructor of `any`.

```
struct any {
  std::type_info const& _info;
  void* _address;
  Comparer _comparer;
};

template <typename T>
any::any(T* t):
  _info(typeid(*t)),
  _address(dynamic_cast<void*>(t)),
  _comparer(make_comparer(t))
{
}
```

Then, we provided a specialization of `less` (or `operator<`)

```
bool operator<(any const& lhs, any const& rhs) {
  if (lhs._info.before(rhs._info)) { return true; }
  if (rhs._info.before(lhs._info)) { return false; }
  return (*lhs._comparer)(lhs._address, rhs._address);
}
```

*Note: encapsulation, etc... are left as an exercise to the reader*

Answer (score 3):

If you can change type in container, there is [Boost.TypeErasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html). It provides easy way to customize `any`. For example I'm using such typedef for similar purpose:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/operators.hpp>

using Foo = boost::type_erasure::any<
    boost::mpl::vector<
        boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
        boost::type_erasure::equality_comparable<>,
        boost::type_erasure::typeid_<>,
        boost::type_erasure::relaxed
    >
>;
```

`Foo` behaves exactly the same as `boost::any`, except that it can be compared for equality and use `boost::type_erasure::any_cast` instead of `boost::any_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this algorithm come in handy >
http://signmotion.blogspot.com/2011/12/boostany.html

Compare two any-values by type and content. Attempt convert string to number for equals.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create new class. Try to use xany https://sourceforge.net/projects/extendableany/?source=directory xany class allows to add new methods to any's existing functionality. By the way there is a example in documentation which does exactly what you want (creates comparable_any).

Comment: Doesn't seem to compile on clang

Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.78) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

Also what is the license for this code?